# How To Create GridView In Titanium Alloy

Tags: javascript, ios, gridview, titanium, titanium-alloy

How to create GridView for iOS (iPhone/iPhone5/ iPad) How to get Gridview in Potrait 33 matrix and in landscape 4*2 matrix.

```
var topGrid = 0;
    var leftGrid = 0;
    var  containerHeight = 108;
    var  containerWidth = 106;
//     
    for(var i=0; i<9; i++){   

     var view_Grid = Titanium.UI.createView({
         width:containerWidth,
         height:containerHeight,
         backgroundColor:'red',
         borderColor:'green',
         borderRadius:'4',
         borderWidth:'2',

        }); 
        // alert(leftGrid);
        if(leftGrid > 212){
            topGrid = topGrid+containerHeight;
            leftGrid = 0;
        }   

         view_Grid.top=topGrid;
         view_Grid.left=leftGrid;
        leftGrid = leftGrid + containerWidth;

        $.view_GridBox.add(view_Grid);  
    }
```

Can any one advice me how to achieve it in dynamically for IOS.

@All Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'white'
});
win.open();

var scroll = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    top : '50',
    bottom : '50',
    left : '0',
    right : '0',
    backgroundColor : 'black',
    contentWidth : '98%',
    layout : 'horizontal'
});
win.add(scroll);

var view = [];

for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
    view[i] = Ti.UI.createView({
        height : '63',
        width : '63',
        left : '12',
        top : '15',
        backgroundColor : 'cyan'
    });
    scroll.add(view[i]);
}
var blank = Ti.UI.createView({
    height : '20',
    width : '110%'
});
scroll.add(blank);